# Trying to call a workflow in a private repo under same organization but getting error

Tags: cypress, github-actions, private-repository

We are trying to call a workflow from a private repo under our organization. Both repos are private repos under the same organization.

```
Organisation A --> private - repo-1 / .github\workflows\qatest.yml
Organisation A --> private - repo-2 / .github\workflows\test.yml
```

But while running we are getting error like :

Error details:

```
 RequestError [HttpError]: Not Found
    at /home/runner/work/_actions/actions/github-script/v6/dist/index.js:6172:21
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  status: 404
```

`repository 'https://github.com/somebookingtest/e2e-cypress/' not found`

Could someone please advise on how to fix this issue here ?

Below is the action from //repo2/  `test.yml`

```
name: end to end testing
on:
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, synchronize, reopened]
jobs:
  first:
    name: end to end testing
    uses: somebookingtest/e2e-cypres/.github/workflows/maintest.yml@main-fixes
    permissions: read-all
    with:
      environment: qastaging
      tag: "@e2etests"
  second:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Trigger Workflow
        uses: actions/github-script@v6
        with:
          script: |
            github.rest.actions.createWorkflowDispatch({
              owner: 'booking',
              repo: 'e2e-cypres',
              workflow_id: 'maintest.yml',
              ref: 'main-fixes',
            })
```

Comment: Looks like the workflow is not visible. See https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows#access-to-reusable-workflows and https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/sharing-actions-and-workflows-from-your-private-repository for more details.

Comment: Any better way to resolve the above problem ?

Comment: Other than what the official docs have i.e. https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/managing-your-repositorys-settings-and-features/enabling-features-for-your-repository/managing-github-actions-settings-for-a-repository#allowing-access-to-components-in-a-private-repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use PAT - Personal Access Token instead of the default one - the default one only allows reading the active repository.

1. [Create a personal access token](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@3.4/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token)
2. [Add it to your secrets](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/encrypted-secrets#creating-encrypted-secrets-for-a-repository)
3. add: `github-token: ${{ secrets.MY_PAT }}` to your second job as documented [here](https://github.com/actions/github-script#using-a-separate-github-token)

```
name: end to end testing
on:
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, synchronize, reopened]
jobs:
  first:
    name: end to end testing
    uses: somebookingtest/e2e-cypres/.github/workflows/maintest.yml@main-fixes
    permissions: read-all
    with:
      environment: qastaging
      tag: "@e2etests"
  second:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Trigger Workflow
        uses: actions/github-script@v6
        with:
          github-token: ${{ secrets.MY_PAT }}
          script: |
            github.rest.actions.createWorkflowDispatch({
              owner: 'booking',
              repo: 'e2e-cypres',
              workflow_id: 'maintest.yml',
              ref: 'main-fixes',
            })
```

Comment: If possible could you provide a usage example as per above the test.yml file ?

Comment: @soccerway updated my answers with the details

Comment: Could you please advise what could be the issue here ?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75166565/how-to-run-cron-jobs-in-github-action-for-a-particular-day-and-time

Comment: Question, in your example, the `first` job here wouldn't actually work, and is redundantly specified, no? Because execution of first workflow is actually done by the github-script?

Comment: Apparently PAT is no longer required as of September 2022 - https://github.blog/changelog/2022-09-08-github-actions-use-github_token-with-workflow_dispatch-and-repository_dispatch/