# How to run cron jobs in github action for a particular day and time

Tags: cypress, github-actions

How to run cron jobs automatically every `Thursday at 10:30 am` Australian Standard time irrespective of any other action? I have tried the below, but not sure if it's running. Could someone please advise?

I have the `schedule.yml` file in my branch.
Should I add the `schedule.yml` somewhere else?

**Branch**: `cypress-schedule-test-ci-100`

`.github\workflows\schedule.yml`

```yaml
name: Cypress E2E Tests
on:
  schedule:
  - cron: "30 10 * * 4"
env:
  CYPRESS_BOOKING_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.CYPRESS_BOOKING_PASSWORD }}
  CYPRESS_BOOKING_FREE_USER_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.CYPRESS_BOOKING_FREE_USER_PASSWORD }}

jobs:
  install:
    runs-on: ubuntu-22.04
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Install dependencies
        uses: cypress-io/github-action@v2
        with:
          # just perform install
          runTests: false
  tests:
    runs-on: ubuntu-22.04
    needs: install
    steps:
      - name: Check out code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Install dependencies
        uses: cypress-io/github-action@v2
        with:
          # perform installation
          runTests: false
      - name: Run E2E tests
        run: npm run cy:run -- --env grepTags="@MainUITests+-@Failing",ENV="qaserver" --browser chrome
      - name: Upload Results
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        if: failure()
        with:
          name: cypress-screenshots
          path: cypress/screenshots
      - uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        if: always()
        with:
          name: cypress-videos
          path: cypress/videos
```

Comment: The [schedule](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#schedule) uses UTC time. Have you adjusted the configuration for that? Also, you need to account for this also: **Note: The schedule event can be delayed during periods of high loads of GitHub Actions workflow runs. High load times include the start of every hour. To decrease the chance of delay, schedule your workflow to run at a different time of the hour.**

Comment: Yes I have added the UTC time here which should ideally run  the test 3:15 PM AEST time 
`schedule:
    - cron: "20 5 * * *"  `

Comment: The time given in question is as per the UTC time while raising the question.

Comment: Right. The only logical conclusion seems to be that it was delayed according to that note. Your workflow looks good to me.

Comment: Thank you mate, quick question, I have this workflow in my branch. Should that only work in main branch ?

Comment: Oh, I assumed that it was your default branch. It won't work in any other branch. It works only for the default branch i.e. **Scheduled workflows run on the latest commit on the default or base branch.**

Comment: Ah... that could be the issue...ok then I need to test this cron schedule in main ? I will create a pull request from `my_branch -->  main `  and will check it ?

Comment: Please see the [schedule](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#schedule) for details. For a quick test, you may configure it for the default branch with some time that runs sooner (e.g. schedule it to run in the next 5 minutes). You may cancel it when it runs if you don't need it right away or add a condition so that it won't do anything.

Comment: Yes, you got it. Configure it for the default branch i.e. `main` in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While working with the [schedule](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#schedule) cron job, the following points need to keep in mind:

> You can schedule a workflow to run at specific UTC times using POSIX cron syntax.

So, you might need to adjust it according to your time zone.

> Scheduled workflows run on the latest commit on the default or base branch.

It should be scheduled for the default branch e.g. `main`. Apparently, this seems to be the reason why your scheduled job isn't working.

And,

> Note: The `schedule` event can be delayed during periods of high loads of GitHub Actions workflow runs. High load times include the start of every hour. To decrease the chance of delay, schedule your workflow to run at a different time of the hour.

You need to account for such delays due to high loads.

Comment: @soccerway: Thanks! Have you tested it with the `main` branch for the current time or do you plan to wait for it to run as scheduled?